# Chi-Squared Statistic to test for conditional independence

Tags: chi-squared-test, independence, conditional-independence

How can compute the chi-square statistic between the random variables X and Y given an evidence variable Z? I want to test if X & Y are conditionally independent given  Z.

Assume all X,Y, Z are binary.

Say X = [1,1,1,0]
Y is [0,1,1,0]
and Z is [1,0,0,1]

if I compute the Chi-Square test between just X & Y I get χ2 =0.444

How Can I compute the Chi-Square test between X & Y when I have an evidence random variable Z ? ie How does the formula to compute chi-square statistic change ?

Comment: Can you please add more details to your question? As it stands, it is too basic/vague for this site.

Comment: @Alex added some details. I want to use the chi-square test to check if two variables ( X and Y) are conditionally independent given an observation variable(Z).

Comment: Look at the [graduate admissions Berkeley](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/1739581.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3Ace153cbbe0e5fea084e3c82a33d55097) paper for a famous example.